# Unable to import MSOnline module in PowerShell (x86)

Tags: powershell, office365

I am getting error when trying to run below commands in PowerShell (x86) but same commands are working in PowerShell (64 bit).

Command executed in PowerShell (x86) : I've tried commands in two different ways but error is same:

1. `Import-Module MSOnline`
2. `Import-Module -Name C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MSOnline -Verbose`

```
Error in PowerShell (x86) : Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MSOnline\1.
1.183.57\Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PSModule.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to
load a program with an incorrect format.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module -Name C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Module ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], BadImageFormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Output of command in PowerShell (x86) and showing null in `Exported Commands: Get-Module MSOnline -listavailable`

```
Directory: C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   1.1.183.57 MSOnline


Output of command in PowerShell (64 bit) :
Directory: C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   1.1.183.57 MSOnline                            {Get-MsolDevice, Remove-MsolDevice, Enable-MsolDevice, Dis...
```

Comment: Why the need to use 32 bit??

Comment: @teylyn : I am using batch commands and running using bot. when bot is actually running this imported batch script. it is calling Powershell script (x86) not powershell (64 bit). which is causing bot with mentioned error. If any how, i can run script in PowerShell (64 bit) then i will achieve this objective. My objective is to connect with Msolservice and allocate licenses to new users but bot is actually before connection step. (pre-requisite is to import-Module MSModule and then connect with MSolservice.) I hope you understand the bigger picture.

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-msonlinev1?view=azureadps-1.0) _"Effective October 20, 2014, the Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell (32-bit version) is discontinued. "_

Answer (score 0):

Please use below command it will be installed msmodule

```
Install-Module MSOnline -AllowClobber
```

Comment: I've used this script to switch and run commands in PowerShell (64 bit) instead of PowerShell (x86).

Comment: "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
$PathToPowerShell64bit = Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:Windir\WinSxS | Where-Object {$_.FullName -match 'amd64_microsoft-windows-powershell-exe'}
$PowerShell64bitExe = Get-ChildItem -Path $PathToPowerShell64bit.FullName -Filter PowerShell.exe | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
& $PowerShell64bitExe -file '\MSOnline.ps1'"